# How to run multiple experiments in parallel and select best cases for refinement in deep reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am working on a custom environment using gym and currently trying to parallelize the training of my D3QN model as it is taking a lot of time to finish an episode.

Is there a way to parallelize the training and take only best cases for refinement using Keras and tensorflow?

```
    def run(self):
        reward_list = []
        ave_reward_list = []
        decay_step = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        for e in range(self.EPISODES):
            state = self.env.reset()
            state = np.asarray(state).reshape((1, 24))
            state = (state - state.mean()) / state.std()
            done = False
            i = 0
            first_ps = 0
            total_reward = 0
            #counter = 0
            while not done:
                #self.env.render()
                decay_step += 1
                action, explore_probability = self.act(state, decay_step)
                acting = [action, first_ps]
                next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(acting)
                next_state = np.asarray(next_state).reshape((1, 24))
                next_state = (next_state - next_state.mean()) / next_state.std()
                #print('next_state: {}'.format(next_state))
                first_ps = 1

                self.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
                state = next_state
                i += 1
                total_reward += reward
                #print(total_reward)
                
                #counter +=1
                #if counter==100:
                    #self.update_target_model()
                    #counter = 0
                
                if done:
                    # track the reward list
                    reward_list.append(total_reward)
                    if (e+1) % 100 == 0:
                        ave_reward = np.mean(reward_list)
                        ave_reward_list.append(ave_reward)
                        reward_list = []
                    
                    # every step update target model
                    self.update_target_model()

                    # every episode, plot the result
                    average = self.PlotModel(i, e)
                    
                    # every episode, plot the total_reward
                    #average_reward = self.PlotModel_reward(total_reward, e)
                    
                    print("episode: {}/{}, iterations: {}, e: {:.2}, average: {}, tot_reward: {}".format(e, self.EPISODES, i, explore_probability, average, total_reward))
                    
                    if e==self.EPISODES-1:
                        hours, rem = divmod((time.time() - start_time), 3600)
                        minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
                        print("The running time is: {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))
                        
                        print("Saving trained model to", self.Model_name)
                        self.save(self.Model_name+'_'+str(int(total_reward))+".h5")
                        
                self.replay(done)
```

My main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        env_name = 'trainSim-v0'
        agent = DQNAgent(env_name)
        agent.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only do this if you have multiple GPU. one GPU can only focus on 1 task, since your model is already slow so you need to upgrade your hardware, you either need more GPUs to train single model(opposite of your question). or you can get better GPU to train model.

https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/